# How to install Canon PIXMA MX882 using CUPS 1.4.8 in Puppy Linux Precise 5.7.1

Tags: printer

I need help installing my Canon PIXMA MX882 network printer using the pre-installed CUPS 1.4.8 in Puppy Linux Retro 5.7.1 (Full Install) on my Gateway Solo 9100 (Pentium II 300 MHz with 160 Mb Memory), which connects to my network and internet via my Linksys WPC54G V3 PCMCIA Wireless Adapter.

From the Setup Menu, I click on the CUPS Printer Wizard, I then press the “Yes” button on the Xdialog question (“Do you want to add a new printer?”), which takes me to the ”Home” tab at “localhost:631” in the Opera web browser. I then press the “Add Printer” button in the “Administration” tab, which takes me to the “Add Printer Screen” where it displays three group of options. The first group contain options related to "Local Printers" (LPT #1, SCSI Printer or pdf writer), which do not apply in my case because I am trying to install a network printer. The second group is for "Discovered Network Printers", which shows no options since CUPS would not detect my Canon printer, which is always on (Also note that CUPS would not detect it through the “Find New Printers” button in the “Administration” tab). The third group “Other Network Printers” offers the following options:

- Internet Printing Protocol (http)
- Internet printing Protocol (ipp)
- LPD/LPR Host or Printer
- AppSocket/HP jetDirect
- Windows Printer Via SAMBA (smbclient)
- Windows Printer using smbclient, and
- Backend Error Handler

Since CUPS is unable to find my printer on the network automatically, I guess that I have to select one of the options from the third group. But selecting any of those options and pressing the “Continue” button takes you to a screen, which requires entering an explicit “URI” specific to the printer’s make and model in a “Connection:” field.

Can someone help me choose which of the displayed options above to select and the correct “URI” (whatever that means) for my printer (Canon PIXMA MX882)?

Or better yet, can someone guide me as to how to make CUPS detect my printer automatically, so I can select it and proceed from there with the wizard?

I would greatly appreciate your help, and please explain as simple as possible since I have never used Linux before (I have always been a Microsoft Windows user), and I have absolutely no knowledge of its terminology, which I find extremely confusing and very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same in CUPS 1.2.

1. Create user in windows where the printer is plugged-in.
2. Printer must be shared.
3. Choose Windows printer via samba in cups.
4. Device URI contains:

   ```
   smb://"user":"passwd"@"host(domain name of windows PC)"/"printer"
   ```